# Keep other variables when executing get_dummies in Pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dummy-variable

I have a DataFrame with an ID variable and another categorical variable. I want to create dummy variables out of the categorical variable with get_dummies.

```
dum = pd.get_dummies(df)
```

However, this makes the ID variable disappear. And I need this ID variable later on to merge to other data sets.

Is there a way to keep other variables. In the documentation of get_dummies I could not find anything. Thanks!

Comment: Can you add a sample for your `df` to the question? My first attempt would be to exclude `ID` when calling `get_dummies` and then, later on adding the column again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer. You can concatenate the dummies data set to the original data set like shown below. As long as you don't re-order the data in the meantime.

```
df = pd.concat([df, dum], axis=1)
```

Comment: That's correct, but if your df has some index you may face problems as _concat_ method merges based on index while _get_dummies_ resets it. In this case, I'd recommend using [set_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) method: `df = pd.concat([df, dum.set_index(df.index)], axis=1)`

Comment: Is there still no argument implemented in get_dummies that let's you do this easily? Seems kind of like a common problem...

Answer (score 9):

You can also copy the original column into a new one before executing get_dummies. E.g.,

```
df['dum_orig'] = df['dum']
df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['dum'])
```